# RxJS5 groupBy dropping the first item from first group?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm having difficulties to see why this code is dropping the first element?

```
const Rx = require("@reactivex/rxjs")

const requestQueue = Rx.Observable.from([
  {type: "show.json", value: "1"},
  {type: "tweets.json", value: "A"},
  {type: "show.json", value: "2"},
  {type: "tweets.json", value: "B"}
])

requestQueue.groupBy(request => request.type).bufferCount(2).mergeMap(requestSubstreams => {
  return requestSubstreams[0].merge(requestSubstreams[1])
}).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
{ type: 'tweets.json', value: 'A' }
{ type: 'show.json', value: '2' }
{ type: 'tweets.json', value: 'B' }
```

Been doing some experiments, it's always the first element that gets dropped.

This is the link to RxFiddle: http://rxfiddle.net/#type=editor&code=Y29uc3QgcmVxdWVzdFF1ZXVlID0gUnguT2JzZXJ2YWJsZS5mcm9tKFsKICB7dHlwZTogInNob3cuanNvbiIsIHZhbHVlOiAiMSJ9LAogIHt0eXBlOiAidHdlZXRzLmpzb24iLCB2YWx1ZTogIkEifSwKICB7dHlwZTogInNob3cuanNvbiIsIHZhbHVlOiAiMiJ9LAogIHt0eXBlOiAidHdlZXRzLmpzb24iLCB2YWx1ZTogIkIifQpdKQoKcmVxdWVzdFF1ZXVlLmdyb3VwQnkocmVxdWVzdCA9PiByZXF1ZXN0LnR5cGUpLmJ1ZmZlckNvdW50KDIpLm1lcmdlTWFwKHJlcXVlc3RTdWJzdHJlYW1zID0+IHsKICByZXR1cm4gcmVxdWVzdFN1YnN0cmVhbXNbMF0ubWVyZ2UocmVxdWVzdFN1YnN0cmVhbXNbMV0pCn0pLnN1YnNjcmliZSh4ID0+IGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKHgpKQ== ... but I haven't figured out how to interpret it.

I have to resort to this code (using partition) in order to get the result I was expecting:

```
const requestQueue = Rx.Observable.from([
  {type: "show.json", value: "1"},
  {type: "tweets.json", value: "A"},
  {type: "show.json", value: "2"},
  {type: "tweets.json", value: "B"}
])

const requestSubstreams = requestQueue.partition(request => request.type == "show.json")
const showJsonSubstream = requestSubstreams[0]
const tweetsJsonSubstream = requestSubstreams[1]

showJsonSubstream.merge(tweetsJsonSubstream).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Can you help point out what's the issue / caveat with groupBy?

Comment: Found related post in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043728/rxjs-groupby-and-combineall-operators-seem-to-omit-output

Comment: Why do you have a `bufferCount` operator between the `groupBy` and the `merge`? What behaviour were you expecting that to effect?

Comment: Right, I noticed that bufferCount seems to be the culprit here (not sure how / why). But I need it there because I need to get all the groupings ( I want to connect / combine the observable of group 1 with the observable of group 2 in some ways, within that mergeMap ). Any alternative?

Comment: It's not clear why you are using `groupBy` or `partition` to separate values by `type` only to later recombine them into the same stream. Perhaps you should explain what it is that you are trying to achieve. With a marble diagram, if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740280/3443096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To @cartant : it has to do with this code (in this code) the letters and numbers are from  separate observables.

```
const letterArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
const letterStream = Rx.Observable.zip(
  Rx.Observable.from(letterArr),
  Rx.Observable.range(0, letterArr.length - 1), 
  (letter, index) => Rx.Observable.of({letter, index}).delay(
    index == 0 ? 0 : index < 5 ? (index == 2 ? 2000 : 5000) : 20000000
  )
).concatAll().multicast(new Rx.Subject())
//A emitted at 0s, B at 5s, C at 7s, D at 12s, E at 17s, F at ... never

const numberStream = Rx.Observable.zip(
  Rx.Observable.range(1, 20),
  Rx.Observable.interval(2000).startWith(-1).map(x => x +1),
  (number, index) => ({number, index})
).multicast(new Rx.Subject())
//1 emitted at 0s, 2 at 2s, 3 at 4s, ...

const slowedDownNumberStream = Rx.Observable.zip(
  numberStream,
  Rx.Observable.zip(
    letterStream,
    Rx.Observable.interval(10000).startWith(-1).map(x => x +1)
  ).timeoutWith(11000, Rx.Observable.interval(2000).startWith(-1)),
  (number, index) => ({number, index})
)

Rx.Observable.merge(letterStream, slowedDownNumberStream).subscribe(x => console.log(new Date(), " > ", x))
letterStream.connect()
numberStream.connect()
```

RxFiddle: http://rxfiddle.net/#type=editor&code=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

You see, I use the letterStream in the slowedDownNumberStream.

My situation now, I have one single stream as input (where letters and numbers are mixed), so I need to partition them, using groupBy..., and since I need both inside the mergeMap, so I put bufferCount between the groupBy and mergeMap.